# SQL - query with INNER JOIN is not working propely

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, inner-join

I have the table `table_tudo` and `followItem`, on the table `table_tudo` i have 1 column called `tipo` that can have one of three values `tipoEp, tipoOv and tipoFm`, on these two tables i want to `INNER JOIN` the column `dateMD` and `itemName` after this i want to print out on the screen only the itens that match this contidion `table_tudo.dateMD > followItem.dateMD AND followItem.user_id = :user_id AND table_tudo.tipo = :tipoEp OR table_tudo.tipo = :tipoFm OR table_tudo.tipo = :tipoOv`.

On the end of my query i used `GROUP BY` because it was showing duplicated rows.

I'm not able to use `AND` to `INNER JOIN` 2 columns from 2 tables, then i tryed to use `OR` and it worked, but now i have another problem, the condition `table_tudo.dateMD > followItem.dateMD` is not working for the `table_tudo.tipo = :tipoFm OR table_tudo.tipo = :tipoOv` the rows from these `tipo`'s is all printed on the screen, the conditon only works for `table_tudo.tipo = :tipoEp`.

What's wrong with my query? PS: the variables inside the `bindParam` are global variables.

```
$MTEpPRP = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table_tudo` INNER JOIN `followItem` ON `table_tudo`.`itemName` = `followItem`.`itemName` OR `table_tudo`.`dateMD` = `followItem`.`dateMD` WHERE `table_tudo`.`dateMD` > `followItem`.`dateMD` AND `followItem`.`user_id` = :user_id AND `table_tudo`.`tipo` = :tipoEp OR `table_tudo`.`tipo` = :tipoFm OR `table_tudo`.`tipo` = :tipoOv GROUP BY `table_tudo`.`id`");
$MTEpPRP->bindParam(':tipoEp', $tipoEp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$MTEpPRP->bindParam(':tipoFm', $tipoFm, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$MTEpPRP->bindParam(':tipoOv', $tipoOv, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$MTEpPRP->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);      
$MTEpPRP->execute();
```

I made some tests and i also realized that the rows from `table_tudo.tipo = :tipoFm OR table_tudo.tipo = :tipoOv` is only printed out on the screen if i have this line on my query `table_tudo.tipo = :tipoEp`.

I believe that the problem is on the `INNER JOIN` because i tested these query bellow and it worked:

```
$MTEpPRP = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table_tudo` WHERE `table_tudo`.`tipo` = :tipoOv");    
$MTEpPRP->bindParam(':tipoOv', $tipoOv, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$MTEpPRP->execute();

$MTEpPRP = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table_tudo` WHERE `table_tudo`.`tipo` = :tipoFm");  
$MTEpPRP->bindParam(':tipoFm', $tipoFm, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$MTEpPRP->execute();

$MTEpPRP = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table_tudo` WHERE `table_tudo`.`tipo` = :tipoFm OR `table_tudo`.`tipo` = :tipoOv");  
$MTEpPRP->bindParam(':tipoFm', $tipoFm, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$MTEpPRP->bindParam(':tipoFm', $tipoOv, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$MTEpPRP->execute();
```

Comment: `i tested this query` which query? there are so many

Comment: This is not an answer, but declaring an alias when joining tables is a big help to shorten you code.

Comment: Natalie, kindly tells us the Primary Keys of these two tables. Or you can send sample data in the tables. This is just to understand the behavior of the tables

Comment: Without data, and parameter values, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @AnuraAdhikari the Primary Key on the table `table_tudo` is `id` and on the table `followItem` is `num` and both are with `AUTO_INCREMENT`. "Send sample data in the tables" i don't know what it means...

Comment: @Used_By_Already I already said the paramters values on my question, i think you should take a look

Comment: How do we compare the parameter value to anything? it needs both, which is what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for dates to be equal AND greater than at the same time

You probably need to use parentheses with the OR conditions to control the way they are interpreted.

You are relying on MySQL's non-standard group by to filter out unwanted rows, but these are just approximations.

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_tudo`
INNER JOIN `followItem` ON `table_tudo`.`itemName` = `followItem`.`itemName`

   OR `table_tudo`.`dateMD` = `followItem`.`dateMD`   << not making sense
WHERE `table_tudo`.`dateMD` > `followItem`.`dateMD`   << not making sense

 AND `followItem`.`user_id` = :user_id
 AND (                                     << use parentheses
      `table_tudo`.`tipo` = :tipoEp
   OR `table_tudo`.`tipo` = :tipoFm
   OR `table_tudo`.`tipo` = :tipoOv
     )                                     << use parentheses
GROUP BY `table_tudo`.`id`                 << select * with group by is MySQL nightmare
```

see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Yea, i just added a parentheses as you did on your code, and it solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: I want to apply the condition `table_tudo.dateMD > followItem.dateMD` only for `:tipoEp` is this possible?

Comment: Yes, to do this you have to "combine" the wanted combination of conditions together with parentheses e.g.  `( table_tudo.dateMD > followItem.dateMD AND table_tudo.tipo = :tipoEp )` but without **sample data** end the **expected result** I can't really offer much more

Answer (score 1):

Your primary query was mostly on target.  Here it is formatted to read a little easier the correlation of tables.  I added aliases for the table names to simplify too.  The JOIN between the T and FI (alias) tables are just those that qualify the records... matching on the ID, user and with the date GREATER.  That is part 1.

NEXT, is the limitation on the "TIPO" qualifier.  I changed this to using an IN clause, so it is true if TIPO is ANY of those in the list.

```
SELECT 
      * 
   FROM 
      table_tudo T
         INNER JOIN followItem FI
            ON T.itemName = FI.itemName
            AND FI.user_id = :user_id 
            AND T.dateMD > FI.dateMD 
   WHERE 
      T.tipo IN ( :tipoEp, :tipoFm, :tipoOv )
   GROUP BY 
      T.id
```

The reason you were probably having the problem with records not returned properly is you had the OR conditions after all the ands without any parenthesis.  So as soon at it had a match, it joined across the board, probably in a Cartesian result.

Your GROUP by, you need to add the list of columns from each table to help limit duplicates and which respective table the columns are you care about.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your query, when compared to description of the goal :

- the 2 conditions in your joind need an `AND`, not an `OR`. Also most `WHERE` conditions can be moved directly to the `JOIN`, which makes the logic easier to understand
- issues with operator prescedence in your `WHERE` clause ; you need to enclose the `OR`part in parenthethis, or it won't do what you think `... AND (`table_tudo`.`tipo`= :tipoEp OR`table_tudo`.`tipo`= :tipoFm OR`table_tudo`.`tipo`= :tipoOv). Better yet, use an`IN` clause, which is much easier to read

Updated query :

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `table_tudo`
    INNER JOIN `followItem` 
        ON `table_tudo`.`itemName` = `followItem`.`itemName` 
        AND `table_tudo`.`dateMD` = `followItem`.`dateMD`
        AND `table_tudo`.`dateMD` > `followItem`.`dateMD`
        AND `followItem`.`user_id` = :user_id 
    WHERE  
        `table_tudo`.`tipo` IN (:tipoEp, :tipoFm, `table_tudo`.`tipo` = :tipoOv )
    GROUP BY `table_tudo`.`id`
```

PS : I doubt that the `GROUP BY` is useful, trying removing it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
select * from table_tudo t
inner join followItem f on  t.itemName = f.itemName 
where f.dateMD > t.dateMD 
and f.user_id  = 'user_id' and (t.tipo ='tipoEp' or t.tipo ='tipoFm' or t.tipo 
='tipoOV' )
```